# How can I control where XNA positions the game window at startup?

Tags: c#, xna

I have the following annoyance: Whenever I start debugging an XNA game, the game window pops up in the center of my screen. Since I have a dual monitor system, I'd like to set the default startup position somewhere my second monitor. But, this should only happen in debug modus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing`(as pointed out by Steve H) and then do the following somewhere outside the constructor, like in the `Initialize` override.

```
var form = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
form.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
```

The reason we have the whole namespace in the code is to avoid class name collisions(again, as pointed out by Steve H).

Comment: Point requires a reference to System.Drawing too. Also, it's best not to add a using statements for those two references since they both can create ambiguity with Xna types (Point, for instance).

Comment: So you're saying I need to put `using System.Windows.Forms` at the start of the code? I am getting a namespace error. Probably a simple answer, I'm just new.

Comment: @TankorSmash, You need to right-click on `References` in your solution explorer, hit `Add Reference...`, and then browse to `System.Windows.Forms` and then do the same, but with `System.Drawing`.

Comment: Thanks.  I wrapped mine in an "#if DEBUG" directive so that it won't happen when I go to publish my game.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, Alternatively, make it a setting that is stored when you close. This way it becomes a feature for the end user as well.

Answer (score 5):

To update this question, for MonoGame 3.4 (maybe earlier) you can simply do

`this.Window.Position = new Point(x, y);`

No need to reflect into OpenTK stuff it seems

Answer (score 2):

In MonoGame: [Tutorial: Setting window position in Xna/Monogame](http://projectdrake.net/blog/2013/03/31/tutorial-setting-window-position-in-xnamonogame/)