# Set Monogame window position (OSX)

Tags: c#, macos, xna, monogame

How can I set the position of a game window that I've created in Monogame on Mac OS X? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726667/how-can-i-control-where-xna-positions-the-game-window-at-startup) question but it doesn't work: apparently there is not handle for the window. I'm thinking I might be able to do it with MonoMac somehow... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this in the constructor of your Game-Class?

```
public MyGame()
{
this.Window.ClientBounds.Location  = new Point (x,y);    
}
```